# Error during database connection with jqgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm trying to connect to database from jqgrid. I have this bug in the controller, does anyone know how to fix it?

`Component LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString () "and you can not translate it to express the warehouse.`

When given data rigidly works.
`new {id = 1, cell = new[] {"1", "zzzzzz", "xxxxxx"}}`

In addition, I would like to ask how to add edit to jqgrid?

*View*

```
<asp:Content ID="indexTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:content contentplaceholderid="HeadContent" runat="server">

    <link href="/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#list").jqGrid({
                url: '/Home/LinqGridData/',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['CatID', 'CatName', 'Age'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'CatID', index: 'CatID', width: 40, align: 'left' },
            { name: 'CatName', index: 'CatName', width: 40, editable: true, align: 'left' },
            { name: 'Age', index: 'Age', width: 400, align: 'left' }],
                pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                sortname: 'Id',
                sortorder: "desc",
                viewrecords: true,
                imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
                caption: 'My first grid'
            });
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', "#pager", { edit: true, add: true, del: true });
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('inlineNav', "#pager");
        });
    </script>

</asp:content>

<asp:content contentplaceholderid="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>My Grid Data</h2>
    <table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
    <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>

</asp:content>
```

*Model*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class Cat
    {
        [Key]
        public int CatID { get; set; }
        public string CatName { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Controller*

```
public ActionResult LinqGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
    var context = new CatEntities();

    var jsonData = new
    {
        total = 1, //todo: calculate
        page = page,
        records = context.Cats.Count(),
        rows = (
            from question in context.Cats
            select new
            {
                i = question.CatID,
                cell = new string[] { question.CatID.ToString(), question.CatName, question.Age }
            }).ToArray()
    };
    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I think it's because the question for a moment it is sent to the database,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send this:

```
question.CatID.ToString()
```

to SQL Server because it doesn't know what to do with the method call. If you force enumeration of the set first you can make use of .NET methods in memory:

```
from question in context.Cats.ToList()
```

The problem is going to be balancing performance. If the `Cats` unfiltered set is large performance will suffer as the entire table is loaded into memory. In your case you probably won't notice a difference as you're invoking `ToArray()` later anyway.

If possible, use `Skip()` and `Take()` to implement paging and keep your sets small.

You should also consider storing the result in a variable so that you can reference it for your `rows` and `records` properties rather than hitting the context twice.