# jqGrid - button to add, edit, search didn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I did jqGrid according to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840110/error-during-database-connection-with-jqgrid). I have a few questions. I would be grateful for a piece of code

1. Why add button, edit button a duplicate? **[solved]**
2. What can I do to make it work search, add and editing?
3. Why switching sides stopped working after adding navGrid?

   **UPDATE**

`editurl: "/Home/GridEdit",` I added to the code cshtml.

Controller
ver1

```
public ActionResult GridEdit(int id, string Name, string Age)
{
    Cat e = DB.Cats.SingleOrDefault(p => p.CatID == id);
    if (!(e == null))
    {
        e.CatName = Name;
        e.Age = Age;
        DB.SaveChanges();
        return Content("true");
    }
    else
    {
        return Content("false");
    }
}
```

ver2

```
public ActionResult GridEdit(Cat cat)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        DB.Entry(cat).State = EntityState.Modified;
        DB.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

None of them work...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- 2) Why Search Add Edit Delete not  Working

  - to make your Pagination work YOu Need to add Some Code in your Code behind

    - like for Add product

    `public HttpResponseMessage PostProduct(Product item)
    {
    //Codes
    }`

    - like for Edit product

    `public void PutProduct(int id, Product item)
    {
    //Codes
    }`
  - Rememember these PostProducts,PutProducts are My interface
- 1 )Why add Edit are Duplicate

  - These ToolTips are Editable you can Edit it..Go through Documentation you will find Way

Comment: You still need more explaination?

Comment: If this isn't a problem, then yes.